# Возможно ли использовать в этом предложении слово «затворялся»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, глаголы, лексическая-сочетаемость

*Глаз животного затворялся необычно-толстыми веками.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В БТС русских глаголов:
[**затворя́ться**](https://verbs_ru.academic.ru/1211/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), несов. (сов. *затвори́ться*). Закрываться (закрыться) (о двери, окне и т. п.).

Синонимы: закрываться, смыкаться.

Если животное какое-то особенное и у него глаза с веками чрезмерной толщины, то, думаю, *можно* использовать этот глагол. Нестандартное его употребление заставляет дополнительно обратить внимание на описание необычного животного.

Есть примеры (правда, о людях):
*Звук вокруг стал приглушенным, **глаза затворялись**, а сердцебиение угасало* (Рустам Тунгатаров. Где всегда светит солнце); *Его **глаза затворились**, как врата Рая закрываются при приближении грешника* (Денис Чекалов. Между двух войн).

**Глаз животного затворялся необычно толстыми веками.**
Так, считаю, возможно написать в том случае, если у особи один глаз (или виден автору только один глаз). Или два, но каждый глаз имеет веки разной формы.

"Необычно толстый" пишется раздельно.
*Голова относительно большая, а клюв **необычно толстый*** (из Википедии).

[10 животных с невероятными глазами (фото)](https://online.zakon.kz/Document/?doc_id=31189927&pos=6;-106#pos=6;-106)

Comment: Настолько нестандартное, что хочется в кавычки взять. А то не очень стыкуется.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, "затворялся" употребляется с механизмами или неодушевленными предметами. То есть то, что нужно творить, оживлять, приводить в движение. А животное - это уже тварь, либо это должно быть механическое "животное".

Comment: Тоже так считаю. Не согласен с принятым ответом.

Answer (score 0):

В сказках под старину можно.
В научной и научно-популярной литературе нельзя!
Все равно редактор вычеркнет, как стилистически чуждое слово, и предложит заменить общеупотребительным глаголом - закрывался.